# Displaying an image at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I wanted to display an image( width is 1 px and height is 200px ) at the bottom of the page. But, when i use the code below, i see nothing new on the page.

html:

```
<div id="makeThisBottom">
    <ul class="xy"> 
</ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the css of it:

```
ul.xy { width:auto; margin: 0; padding: 0; display:block; background:url(images/3006.png)    repeat-x bottom left; }

#makeThisBottom{
    position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

This div and ul are right behind of `</body>`(So,probably,no overwriting). How can i fix it and what did i do wrong. Thanks

Comment: When you say 'right behind </html>', they are inside the <body> aren't they? Just a thought.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for that editing:)

Answer (score 2):

Qualify the `height` and `width` of the `ul`: [fsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3mSSn/1/)

```
ul.xy {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
    height: 200px;
    background: url(images/3006.png) repeat-x;
}

#makeThisBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, it partially worked, for visible part of the page, not at the bottom. What i mean is that there are many contents in the page(scroll down thing) So the image is now at the bottom theoretically, but not exactly:(